# How can I selectively overwrite/replace spaces in a string, and pick one character if no spaces exist at a given index?

Tags: powershell

I want to selectively merge the contents of two strings to yield output as shown below:

```
$string1 = "a c"
$string2 = " bd"
$mergedString = "abd"
```

Here is the code snippet I have come up with to achieve this:

```
# First convert strings to arrays
$array1 = $string1.ToCharArray()
$array2 = $string2.ToCharArray()

$array3 = @("", "", "") # array of matching length that will contain result

# Use foreach loop to iterate through each array index
0..2 | foreach {
    if (($array1[$_] -eq " ") -and ($array2[$_] -eq " ")) {
        # rule 1: empty space if both arrays have an empty space at this index
        $array3[$_] = " "
    } elseif (($array1[$_] -eq " ") -and ($array2[$_] -ne " ")) {
        # rule 2: non-space character if only one array has a non-space character
        # at this index
        $array3[$_] = $array2[$_]
    } elseif (($array1[$_] -ne " ") -and ($array2[$_] -eq " ")) {
        $array3[$_] = $array1[$_]
    } elseif (($array1[$_] -ne " ") -and ($array2[$_] -ne " ")) {
        # rule 3: array2 character if both arrays have non-space character at
        # this index
        $array3[$_] = $array2[$_]
    }
}
```

When the loop is done, `$array3` can then be converted into my desired `$mergedString`. My code yields the desired output. However, I want to perform this operation on several pairs of strings, so I am worried that this code (even as a function) may not be the most efficient way to achieve my aim.

I get the feeling regex could be a better bet, but I am still trying to wrap my mind around regex.

Comment: `[Regex]::Replace($string2, ' +', { param($m) $string1.Substring($m.Index, $m.Length) })`

Comment: I hate that I see regex and instantly feel dyslexic... :-( I will have to spend some time on this to understand why it works the way it does. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @PetSerAl Hey thanks so much once again! I think I finally understand most of your regex, but I can't figure out why the $m variable is assigned the space character matched by " +" (at least it seems that's what's happening). Is it an automatic variable that is created/populated when there is a match? It is not listed as an automatic variable in the MSDN docs. Also, why is it fed to param()? I have so far only encountered/used param in functions. References to documentation on this would be so helpful. Thank you once again!

Comment: [One of the `Regex.Replace()` overloads take a `MatchEvaluator` delegate as it's second argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) - the delegate will get the match passed to it as the first argument, which is what @PetSerAl then uses to figure out how many characters to replace with from the first string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you default to the second array if both are non-spaces, you can simplify your rule set to just "take the character from the second array unless space":

```
$array1 = $string1.ToCharArray()
$array2 = $string2.ToCharArray()

$mergedCharArray = 0..($array1.Count - 1) |ForEach-Object {
    if($array2[$_] -eq ' '){
        $array1[$_]
    }
    else {
        $array2[$_]
    }
}
$mergedString = $mergedCharArray -join ''
```

Comment: That doesn't account for if both characters are a space (in which case he uses the space).

Comment: It does - if both arrays contain a space at index $_, it doesn't matter which space character you take :-)

Comment: Wow, now I feel sheepish, you are totally right. Thank you, I can't believe I overlooked something so obvious.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! Really is a much simpler statement of my rules.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer up a `Switch` answer.

```
$string1 = "a c"
$string2 = " bd"
Switch(0..($array1.Count - 1)){
    {$string2[$_] -notmatch '\s'} {$mergedCharArray = "{0}{1}" -f $mergedCharArray, $string2[$_];continue}
    {$string1[$_] -notmatch '\s'} {$mergedCharArray = "{0}{1}" -f $mergedCharArray, $string1[$_];continue}
    default {$mergedCharArray = "$mergedCharArray "}
}
```

So if the current letter of string2 is not whitespace, add that to $mergedCharArray, and move to the loop for the next letter. Else, if the current letter of string1 is not whitespace add that and continue to the loop for the next letter, and if both those fail add a space.

Not really any point to converting them to character arrays. Referring to an index in a string gets you that character anyway, so I skipped that step.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am still getting the hang of Switch.